# Is it possible to view an SQLite database from an Android or iOS emulator inside VS Code?

Tags: sqlite, debugging, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a cross-platform mobile app in Flutter and I ran into a bug with the SQLite database. To debug it, I'd really like to be able to take a look at what's saved in the database. As this is mobile development, the database file is saved inside emulators (and inside my Android phone).

Is it possible to view an SQLite database from an emulator, ideally inside Visual Studio Code (my editor of choice)?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @demsey Not yet. It's not a pressing issue for me anymore, just a nice-to-have right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. First install SQLite-Viewer from marketplace and set it as default viewer for *.db files. Now, identify the db file location in emulator. You can do this easily by printing the database path from your database opening method.

```
_initDatabase() async {
final _directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String dbPath = join(_directory.path, _dbName);
 

debugPrint(dbPath);     -- prints dbPath name to console

return await openDatabase(
  dbPath,
  onCreate: _onCreate,
  version: _dbVersion,
);
```

}

Click on the output db file to open it. This will open the file and you may get a warning that ' The file is not displayed...' with a link to open it. Click on the link and it will show you all available editor options that can open *.db file. Just select SQLite-Viewer and that's it. You can see your db right there!

[SQLITE-Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qwtel.sqlite-viewer)