# Is it possible to view a SQLite in-memory database in VS Code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I am seeding an SQLite in-memory database using C# and I would like to view the data in the database while running the application. Is there a way to do this? What can I examine while debugging? Does it generate some sort of file I can open?

Comment: dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58815675/11107541

Comment: Nope, I saw that one, that's for a database that has a .db file. In memory databases don't have a .db file.

Comment: You can dump it to a file with the backup api (Assuming C# sqlite bindings provide it) or `VACUUM INTO`.

Comment: Can you provide a link with some guidance on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you open a second connection to a `:memory:` database, whether from your IDE or from another program? **No**, you can't. [See this](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

How can you work around this fundamental limitation of memory databases?

1. During development use an on-disk database with an ordinary database file name. Something like this

   ```cs
   var dbFile = ':memory:';
   #if DEBUG
   dbFile = '.\dbFileForDebugging.sqlite';
   #endif
   ```
2. Or, make a snapshot copy of your memory database when you want to view it using a SQL command like this.

   ```sql
   VACUUM INTO .\dbFileForDebugging.sqlite
   ```

If this were my project I would use the first choice, because there would  be less confusion around exactly when the database snapshot happened.